# How can I Remove dotted Noise from Image preserving the dots?

Tags: python, tesseract

I have an image which have a lot of dotted noise in the background. i have tried a lot of filters(median,gaussian) but nothing worked out. Tesseract is missing a lot of text because of these noises 
Then i tried to find all connect component and then pass with area less than 50. but it also removes valid decimal in digits.

```
_, blackAndWhite = cv2.threshold(img, 200, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
nlabels, labels, stats, centroids = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(blackAndWhite, None, None, None, 8, cv2.CV_32S)
sizes = stats[1:, -1] #get CC_STAT_AREA component
img2 = np.zeros((labels.shape), np.uint8)

for i in range(0, nlabels - 1):
    if sizes[i] >= 50:   #filter small dotted regions
        img2[labels == i + 1] = 255
res = cv2.bitwise_not(img2)
```

Here is a part of the image [image]

Comment: Example images would be good to get a better impression of the problem.

Comment: hey i have updated the image

Answer (score 0):

Check `scikit-image` docs about denoising:

- https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/filters/plot_denoise.html
- https://scikit-image.org/docs/0.12.x/auto_examples/filters/plot_denoise.html
- https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/filters/plot_nonlocal_means.html
- https://scikit-image.org/docs/0.12.x/auto_examples/xx_applications/plot_rank_filters.html

I would also try to use [morphological operators](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/applications/plot_morphology.html).

[Local thresholding](https://scikit-image.org/docs/0.14.x/auto_examples/xx_applications/plot_thresholding.html) might also be a better choice for preprocessing.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('path_image', 0)
blackAndWhite = cv2.threshold(img, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

nlabels, labels, stats, centroids = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(blackAndWhite, None, None, None, 8, cv2.CV_32S)
sizes = stats[1:, -1] 
img2 = np.zeros((labels.shape), np.uint8)

for i in range(0, nlabels - 1):
    if sizes[i] >= 50:   #filter small dotted regions
        img2[labels == i + 1] = 255

res = cv2.bitwise_not(img2)

cv2.imwrite('res.png', res)
```